# Ruby capture stderr output from bash script execution

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bash, stderr

I can currently redirect `stdout` to a string variable in ruby/rails by simply running the command in bash and setting the result to my string variable as follows.

```
val = %x[ #{cmd} ]
```

where `cmd` is a string that represents a bash command.

However, this only captures `stdout`, for I want to capture `stderr` and set it to a string in ruby -- any ideas?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Simply redirect it:

```
val = %x[ #{cmd} 2>&1 ]
```

If you want to capture output from stderr only, close the file descriptor for stdout after copying it to fd 2.

```
val = %x[ #{cmd} 2>&1 >/dev/null ]
```

Comment: Just one of those early morning questions that I really didn't think over more than once. :D

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Open3.popen3`:

```
require 'open3'
stdin, stdout, stderr, wait_thread = Open3.popen3('ping -Z')
# => [#<IO:fd 9>, #<IO:fd 10>, #<IO:fd 12>, #<Thread:0x007fd3d30a0ce0 sleep>]

stderr.gets # => "ping: illegal option -- Z\n"
stdout.gets # => nil
```